# Laravel - Missing required parameters for [Route: reset-password.index]

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

i'm just a newbie in Laravel, so still not that good to work on such ready projects,
anyway when ever users try to reset password it fails showing that:

```
~/public_html$ php artisan queue:work
[2021-05-29 19:52:02][182577] Processing: App\Mail\Core\ResetPassword
[2021-05-29 19:52:02][182577] Failed:     App\Mail\Core\ResetPassword
```

and when i checked the log files, i found this error:

```
[previous exception] [object] (Illuminate\\Routing\\Exceptions\\UrlGenerationException(code: 0): Missing required parameters for [Route: reset-password.index] [URI: reset-password/{user}]. at /home/user/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Exceptions/UrlGenerationException.php:17)
```

as a newbie i dunno what to do exactly, searched alot but with no chance.

**here is my route:**

```
 Route::get('reset-password/{user}', [AuthController::class, 'resetPassword'])
   28:     ->name('reset-password.index');
   29: Route::post('reset-password/{user}/update', [AuthController::class, 'updatePassword'])
   30:     ->name('reset-password.update');
```

**and here is my URI:**

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => url()->temporarySignedRoute('reset-password.index', now()->addMinutes(30), ['id' => $user->id])])
    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
@endcomponent
```

**and here is my resetPassword function from AuthController:**

```
 public function resetPassword(Request $request, User $user): View
    {
        $data = $this->service->resetPassword($request, $user->id);

        return view('core.no_header_pages.reset_password', $data);
    }
```

**and here is my resetPassword @ Services:**

```
public function resetPassword(Request $request, $id)
{
    abort_unless($request->hasValidSignature(), 401, 'Invalid Request.');

    $passwordResetLink = url()->signedRoute('reset-password.update', ['user' => $id]);

    return [
        'id' => $id,
        'passwordResetLink' => $passwordResetLink
    ];
}
```

any chance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reset-password` routes parameter is `user` but you're using `id` in your component. Swap it out for `user`

```php
@component('mail::button', [
    'url' => url()->temporarySignedRoute('reset-password.index', now()->addMinutes(30),
    ['user' => $user->id])]) // passing an id but with a named parameter of `user`
    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: done... thank you so much =) i'll accept the answeri n 6 minutes (Y)

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman No worries, the little things are easily overlooked at times.  :)

Comment: i've another error in log would you help me in it please ?

Comment: [2021-05-29 21:04:44] production.ERROR: The provided cwd "" does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): The provided cwd \"\" does not exist. at /home/user/public_html/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:344)
sorry for annoy but i have floods of such error, any clue ?

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman I suspect it is related to a command you're executing but other than that I'm not sure. `cwd` is a linux command for returning the `current working directory` which seems to be returning empty in that error message.

Comment: i'm trying to reach to the problem though sublime search.. i'd post it later forsure thanks alot